# All queries failing with "Error: Unexpected"

Tags: logging, google-bigquery

All queries to one of my BigQuery tables are failing with the following error:

```
Query Failed
Error: Unexpected. Please try again.
```

They take approx 60 sec to run then fail. All through the web interface. Any ideas what could be happenning?

Here is a basic query that isn't working:

```
SELECT timestamp FROM [streaklogsdataset.log_371af6_00000001340064000000_00000001342656000000] order by timestamp desc limit 10
```

If I run a basic query on any of the public data sets they work fine. I wonder if it could be that I'm appending data every 2 mins to the table.

**UPDATE**

Seems to be only happening sporadically now, on the same queries. Sometimes it works and sometimes it fails (after trying to query for 60 seconds or so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the errors and there seemed to be a transient problem accessing the underlying data. I've filed an internal bug and will investigate further, but please let me know if you continue to see the problems.

Comment: Thanks for the investigation, let me know if you need any more info.